# fabric cleanup operation with atexit

Tags: python, fabric, atexit

Is there a received wisdom on how to clean up (e.g. remove temp files etc.) in a fabric task?  if I use the `atexit` module, as I would normally, then I have difficulty because I can't use the `@roles` decorator to decorate the function passed to `atexit.register()`.  Or can I?  How are other fabric users dealing with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also have the same problem. Next Code is not ideal, but I have an implementation like this currently.

fabfile.py

```
from functools import wraps
from fabric.network import needs_host
from fabric.api import run, env

def runs_final(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        if env.host_string == env.all_hosts[-1]:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return None
    return decorated

@needs_host
def hello():
    run('hostname')
    atexit()

@runs_final
def atexit():
    print ('this is at exit command.')
```

Result:

```
fabric$ fab hello -H web01,web02
>[web01] Executing task 'hello'
>[web01] run: hostname
>[web01] out: web01
>[web01] out: 
>[web02] Executing task 'hello'
>[web02] run: hostname
>[web02] out: web02
>[web02] out: 
>
>this is at exit command.
>
>Done.
```

Comment: thanks, this is interesting, and i'll start experimenting with it.  i'm going to leave this question open for a while, and see if anything else turns up.

Comment: well, it seems that there aren't any better answers than this (and this doesn't do what I really wanted).  I suppose I'll stick with my BASH scripts after all.  Thanks!